# Bokeh missing plots in IPython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh

***Maintainers note:*** this question is obsolete. Calling multiple glyph methods on a `figure` automatically combines (and has for many years). For information on modern Bokeh, see:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html

---

---

***OBSOLETE:***

I am running the Bokeh tutorial in the IPython notebook.  It only displays the scatter plot and not the line plot.  From the command-line it renders both plots [separately](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17949100/explorer/bokehtest.html).

How do I get both graphs in the same chart, on top of each other?

```python
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
bplt.output_file("bokehtest.html")
#bplt.output_notebook(url=None)
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.cos(x)
bplt.line(x, y, color="red")
bplt.scatter(x, y, marker="square", color="blue")
bplt.show()
```

Comment: @Jack, "bokeh" is a photography term hijacked by the library.  There are [plenty](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bokeh) of questions about image processing and creating the bokeh effect here.  Without something to specify that it's a library in Python, people are going to abuse it.  Remember, nobody actually reads wiki excerpts...

Comment: @Charles You didn't filter out answers from that list; and only a handful of the [remaining questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bokeh+is%3Aquestion) actually talk about the effect itself.

Answer (score 3):

**OBSOLETE ANSWER:** see https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/output/jupyter.html#jupyter-interactors* for modern Bokeh

---

---

You just need to call `bplt.hold()` before any of the plotting commands, to toggle the "hold state".  The following code works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
bplt.output_file("bokehtest.html")
#bplt.output_notebook(url=None)
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.cos(x)
bplt.hold()  # <--- The important line!!
bplt.line(x, y, color="red")
bplt.scatter(x, y, marker="square", color="blue")
bplt.show()
```

Comment: Page by URL for answer for modern Bokeh shows 404.

Answer (score 1):

***OBSOLETE ANSWER:*** see https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html for modern Bokeh

---

---

Try using the `figure` command like in this example:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
bplt.output_file("bokehtest.html")
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

bplt.figure()
bplt.line(x, y, color="red")
bplt.scatter(x, y, marker="square", color="blue")
bplt.show()
```

Comment: No... right now I have them in the same cell and they come out in two different charts.